# Separate HTMl attributes and values from string

Tags: javascript

I have a list of strings with HTML elements and values.

```
define div with class abc with id xyz
consider image with alt this with src that with class responsive
........
```

I am trying to separate the elements along with their attributes and values like this

```
 div class abc id xyz
 img alt this src that class responsive
 ...........
```

I am using the following method

```
 textElement = string.split ("with")
```

which will give me array and then again separating that. Is there any better way to do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any intention to store `attributes` and `values` separately for any latter use but just want to print them as you have shown in your question then I would suggest to use `replace`

```
textElement = string.replace(/with/g, ""); //i.e. global replacement
```

I hope this will be helpful.